# Android choppy drawing

Tags: android, draw, surfaceview, smoothing, game-loop

I'm writing my very first android game. The graphics are primitive, some rectangles moving through the screen. The game seems smooth but with occasional stutters, every 0.5 - 1.0 secs, and I can't figure out what's causing it. I've already eliminated all the GC calls inside my draw / update routines, enabled hw acceleration in my surfaceView, activity and in the manifest file.

This is how my game loop looks like currently (taken from some sort of tutorial):

```
public void run() {
    while (!terminated) {
        if (!gameEngine.isRunning())
            continue;

        Canvas canvas = null;
        try {
            canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                long beginTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                int framesSkipped = 0;

                gameEngine.update();
                if(canvas != null)
                    gameEngine.draw(canvas);

                long timeDiff = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - beginTime;
                int sleepTime = (int) (FRAME_PERIOD - timeDiff);

                if (sleepTime > 0) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
                    }
                }

                while (sleepTime < 0 && framesSkipped < MAX_FRAME_SKIPS) {
                    gameEngine.update();
                    sleepTime += FRAME_PERIOD;
                    framesSkipped++;
                }

            }
        } finally {
            if (canvas != null)
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }

}
```

If I log the value of timeDiff at every frame, it stays in the 5-15 range, so it doesn't indicate the stutters.

I'm using SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() instead of System.currentTimeMillis() because I've read that System.currentTimeMillis isn't accurate enough. (Or should I be using System.nanoTime() ?)

This isn't the first solution I tried using, and none of them have so far solved my issue. So I suspect the problem may lie somewhere else. I appreciate any help!

Comment: You may want to read https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#loops about game loops.  `System.currentTimeMillis()` uses the "wall clock" and can jump forward or move backward; `System.nanoTim()` and `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` use a monotonic clock that beats steadily while the device is awake.  The Canvas from a SurfaceView Surface is never hardware-accelerated.  On a recent device you can use systrace (http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/systrace.html) to help analyze stuttering.